# Discord Bot unable to read input from discord unless it is mentioned

Tags: c#

I have very little experience with C# and am trying to create a simple Discord Bot that replies to certain messages. However, the bot could only read the input when someone mention it.

```
 if (message.Content.StartsWith("<@1070991931615748157> hi"))
            {
                await message.Channel.SendMessageAsync("I am here, what do you need");
            }
```

It needs the <@1070991931615748157> to be able to read the " hi " text (the number is application ID)
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

It should not be this way is it not because something like

```
 if (message.Content.StartsWith("hi"))
            {
                await message.Channel.SendMessageAsync("I am here, what do you need");
            }
```

should be sufficient. (I am quite sure)
but the bot simply could not read the message.Content.I typed hi or anything in my test sever but it return the empty " Received message"
[![][2]][2]
I hope some passerby could point out the error which I will be very grateful.

Additional code I think might help

```
internal class Bot : IDisposable
    {
        private DiscordSocketClient _client;

        public Bot()
        {
            _client = new DiscordSocketClient();
            _client.MessageReceived += MessageReceivedAsync; 
        }

        public async Task MessageReceivedAsync(SocketMessage message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Received message: " + message.Content);

              if (message.Content.StartsWith("<@1070991931615748157> hi"))
            {
                await message.Channel.SendMessageAsync("I am here, what do you need");
            }


              public void Dispose()
        {
            _client.Dispose();
        }
```

//The BOT does have sufficient permission in the server to read and send messages.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDkEy.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnueM.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution, if you have message intents enabled.

After digging a bit I have come to realize this is an issue to do with the "new" discord way of doing messages/reading them with bots. This exact issue seems to be that you need to add `GatewayIntents.MessageContent` to your `DiscordSocketConfig` as referenced in [#2554 [Bug]: SocketMessage.Content is empty | Discord.NET GitHub](https://github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net/issues/2554). Discord changed this a while ago and many tutorials and old docs do not mention this as a result.

```cs
var config = new DiscordSocketConfig
{
    AlwaysDownloadUsers = false,
    GatewayIntents = GatewayIntents.AllUnprivileged | GatewayIntents.MessageContent
};

SocketClient = new DiscordSocketClient(config);
```

Alternatively you can use `GatewayIntents.All` but it is not recommended as it can cause memory leaks.

This should fix your issue if indeed you have the message intents enabled on the Developers Portal.

---

## Solution, if you have message intents in Discord Developer Portal disabled.

This looks like a simple issue of enabling message intents. If you go to your developer application on discord it should be under 'Bot' and at the bottom before the permissions generator there will be a toggle for 'Message Content Intent'. This should allow the bot to read all messages.

[image: dc, developers sidebar]

[image: dc, message intents disabled]

[image: dc, message intents enabled]

Comment: thank you for your suggestion but the message content intent has always been left as ON. I did make sure to turn it on when I started developing the BOT.

Comment: @Simplylmk I have now updated the answer to include a fix for your issue, please review and accept if it worked, otherwise leave a comment to further help this issue. Kind Regards!

Comment: Dear @SimpleCoder, I have read the documentation about the "new" way of handling messages. I have tried to implement it like this: ``` public Bot() { var discordConfig = new DiscordSocketConfig { GatewayIntents = GatewayIntents.MessageContent }; _client = new DiscordSocketClient(discordConfig); _client.MessageReceived += MessageReceivedAsync; } ```. However, it does not work just yet. I do believe what you found is the root of the problem, thus I will accept your solution for others that came across might be able to make it work. Once again, I sincerely thank you for looking into the matter.

Comment: @Simplylmk not to be that guy, but have you updated the package? Maybe that's one of the issues aswell.

Comment: @Simplylmk I have also added the correct way to do this as shown in [PR #2449](https://github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net/issues/2499). As mentioned you can also try ``GatewayIntents.All`` but that may lead to memory leaks as mentioned in docs and [PR #2482](https://github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net/issues/2482)